# Scala HashMap#contains expects Nothing

Tags: scala

I am trying to use a Scala HashMap like below, and when I try to operate on the HashMap, I get type mismatches. Besides using Java HashMap, how can I write this?

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

object Solution {

  def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
    var lookupTable = new HashMap()

    for(i <- nums.indices) {
      if (lookupTable.contains(target - nums(i)))
        return Array(lookupTable(i), i)
      lookupTable.put(nums(i), i)
    }

    throw new Exception
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of a type ascription, an empty `HashMap` is a `HashMap[Nothing, Nothing]`, which, because mutable HashMaps are invariant means you have a collection which you can't put anything into or get anything out of.

There are thus two ways to fix this:

You can use a mutable `HashMap[Int, Int]`:

```
val lookupTable = HashMap[Int, Int]()
```

Alternatively, you can use an immutable `HashMap`, which is covariant in the value type and technically invariant in the key type, but there's a way around that:

```
var lookupTable = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap()

for (i <- nums.indices) {
  if (lookupTable.contains(target - nums(i))) return Array(lookupTable(i), i)
  else lookupTable = lookupTable ++ Seq((nums(i), i))
}
```